Weak* convergence in Hilbert Spaces
I have two Hilbert spaces $H,V$ s.t. $H \subset V$ (You could think, for example, at $H^1$ and $L^2$). Suppose i have two subsequences, $u_m(t)$ and $v_m$, s.t. $u_m(t) \to u(t)$ weakly* in $L^\infty(0,T;V)$ and $v_m \to v$ strongly in $V$.
How can i prove that $$\int_0^T(u_m,v_m)_H \phi(t)dt \to \int_0^T(u,v)_H\phi(t)dt \ \forall \phi \in D(0,T)$$
where $D(0,T)$ is the space of $C^\infty$ functions with compact support.

Do you have some thoughts on it?

Not really since I am not sure how is defined the weak* convergence in that space. Without that wak* convergence, i could probably use Riesz's theorem to identify a sequence of functions $G_m$ s.t. $(u_m,v_m)_H = (u_m,G_m)_V$ and then i could proably take the limit since both $u_m and \ v_m$ have the weak convergence well defined in V. But again, I am not sure about this
